# Giant Road Bicycle, Comfortable Seat

Tags: road-bike, seatpost

Anyone know of a comfortable seat that is compatible with Giant Bikes?  I took my seatpost to walmart to try and fit the seatpost with the bell gel seatpost with shock absorbers, Had high hopes for this one but the two rails did not line up with the bracket on my bike.  Trying to cut down on the impact from bumpy roads..and I already have biking underwear.

Comment: Hi Stacy, What giant bike is it? Most do use the standard rail system

Comment: The Bike is a Giant Escape 2014 Model.

Comment: I have a Giant Escape 2016 and it uses the standard rail system. I'm 99% sure yours does too so you might want to have another look at the walmart saddles, or better yet try a LBS (Local bike shop) who are better placed to help you.

Comment: My local bike shop, they are pretty unhelpful when it comes to modifying the bike, they say that I shouldn't add weight to the bike... In my opinion I don't mind adding a little additional weight to make the ride more enjoyable.

Comment: Has anyone tried the Cane Creek 3G Thudbuster Long Travel Seatpost, 27.2?

Comment: Hi Stacy, you should find another LBS or be more firm with them! You shouldn't need a new seatpost, just the saddle. A good bike shop should let you try a saddle out before you buy and help you fit it.

Comment: Ok, will try the other bike shop..the reason I went to the bike shop mentioned above is because I purchased the bike there.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all seats and seat posts use a standard width and size rail.  Unless you have a *very* high end setup, it will be compatible.  Since the one that you described didn't fit, I agree with the previous posters that the LBS has got it wrong somehow.

Note that padding is not the only way to reduce saddle pain: getting a saddle that fits is much more effective.  If the saddle is too narrow for your sit-bones, or too wide, then no amount of padding will make you feel comfortable on it.  That's got nothing to do with the size of your .... um ... ass  ... rather, the saddle width has to match the bones of your pelvis.  Some bike stores have a little gel ruler that you sit on and it measures the distance, thus allowing you to choose a saddle with the correct width.

Answer (score 1):

I swear by the seats that have a hole in the center. Terry was the original but now other manufacturers make them as well. I have used them for years. Even with tons of gel the fragile parts are still going to be in direct contact with the seat and that hurts. If you do go that route, you'll have to adjust it a little here and there to make sure that it's doing what it's supposed to.

Comment: Good points - Not sure if OP is a boy or a girl but the concept of a special female's saddle vs the more common male's saddle apply.   Its amazing the difference a few degrees of tilt can make to your riding comfort too.